# How to write below native query in spring boot? The changes are not reflecting on calling the below method updateSiteListName(abc);

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-repositories

```
public interface SiteListRepository extends BaseListRepository<SiteList, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE site_list SET name = REPLACE(name,':text','') WHERE name ILIKE :text", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateSiteListName(@Param("text") String text);
}
```

Comment: P.S using postgresql db

Comment: how about change `REPLACE(name, ':text' ,'')` to `REPLACE(name, :text , '' )`

Comment: @Query(value = "UPDATE site_list SET name = REPLACE(name,:text,'') WHERE name ILIKE %:text%", nativeQuery = true)

This is working for rows having one word but not reflecting for rows having more than 1 word.

For example, i am passing "site" to this method so the rows having only "site" are replaced with '' but rows like "site 1" remains unchanged. can you help identify what's wrong?

Comment: This is working now...

@Query(value = "UPDATE site_list SET name = REPLACE(name,:text,'') WHERE name ILIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:text, '%'))", nativeQuery = true)